# Not firing update or infinite loop when using React.useMemo

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to update a react table data with async data. With this first example, my memo function is not called:

```
export const DataTableComponent = (props: State) => {
    let internal_data: TableData[] = [];
    const data: TableData[] = React.useMemo(
        () => internal_data,
        [internal_data]
    );
    data_provider.get_data().then(table_data => internal_data = table_data);
...
```

Changing `internal_data` to a state, I get the memo function fired, but now I have infinite loop:

```
export const DataTableComponent = (props: State) => {
    const [internal_data, setInternalData] = React.useState<TableData[]>([]);
    const data: TableData[] = React.useMemo(
        () => internal_data,
        [internal_data]
    );
    data_provider.get_data().then(table_data => setInternalData(table_data));
...
```

How to update my memo properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using state is correct, but you should only update state within functions that will be called conditionally. Based on the example you gave, it seems `useEffect` will be the best solution.

```
useEffect(() => {
    data_provider.get_data().then(table_data => setInternalData(table_data));
}, []);
```